# Value of derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and differentiable function. If for a converging sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ with $|a_k| \leq L$ we have $f(a_k) = 0$ forall $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Let $s = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_k$. What can we say about $f'(s)$ ?
Any help would be appreciated.

My attempt: I think $f'(s)=0$. Given $f$ is continuous its easy to see that $f(s)=0$. So $$f'(s) = \lim_{x \to s } \frac{f(x)}{x-s}$$
I am not able to conclude anything from this.

Comment: Confusing to read. What are we assuming and what are we claiming?

Comment: We are assuming that $f$ is a differentiable function and $f(a_k)=0$ for all terms of the sequence and claiming that $f(s)=0$ where $s$ is the limit of the sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to assume that there are infinitely many distict numbers  in the sequence $(a_n)$. If it is a constant  sequence,for example, we can say nothing about $f'(s)$. So let us assume that $a_n$'s are distinct.

Since $f'(s)$ exists it must be equal to the limit of $\frac {f(x_n)} {x_n-s}$ for any sequence $x_n \to s$. Take $x_n=a_n$ to see that  $f'(s)=0$.

Comment: Is it always true that $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(a_k) = L$ for some converging sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ with limit $s$ in the domain of $f$ then $\lim_{x \to s} f(x) = L$ supposing that limit exists ?

Comment: Yes, of course. @Strange

Comment: @Strange  Let $M$ be the limit of $f(x)$. Given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-M|<\epsilon$ for $0<|x-s|<\delta$. If $k$ is sufficiently large that $|a_n-s| <\delta$ so we can out $x=a_k$ in above inequality This gives $|f(a_k)-M|<\epsilon$ for  $k$ is sufficiently large. Letting $k \to \infty$ we get $|L-M| \leq \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we get $L=M$. Is this clear enough?